# Can you use magic commands in the creation of Jupyter Wrapper Kernels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kernel, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am a new coder and have been trying to develop a wrapper kernel written in Python 3 for a different coding language to be used in Jupyter Notebook. I wanted to use the `%store` IPython Magic in its creation since I wanted to create a variable that would be unique to each file utilizing this kernel. Right now, within my notebook I have:

`data = 'test'
%store data
del data`

While within the kernel, I call upon that variable using:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()
ip.magic('store -r test')
```

However, this results in the following error when running the kernel:

```
ip.magic('store -r test')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'magic'
```

I have read that there might be an issue in using magic commands when making a wrapper kernel, despite the fact that it works perfectly fine in a plain Python 3 Notebook (https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6352). I was wondering if this was still true, and, if so, there are any alternatives to this matter. I was also considering another solution ([Share variables between different jupyter notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935670/share-variables-between-different-jupyter-notebooks)) but would prefer not to resort to having messy code if possible. Does anyone have any suggestions and explanations?