# Running one jupyter notebook from another and passing arguments with magic commands

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am unable to pass arguments and or access variables from one jupyter notebook to another:

## using %run with args

First issue I am having is not being able to pass arguments from one notebook to another when using the %run magic command. [magic command docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run). Here is the code from the notebooks: 
Notebook 1:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np
import os
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import random
import warnings
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:95% !important; }</style>"))

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

%run "notebook2.ipynb" 1 2
```

Here is the code in Notebook 2:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import random
import warnings
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:95% !important; }</style>"))

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

print(sys.argv)
```

The output I get doesnt contain either variables that I am trying to pass in. Here is the output with my name redacted `['C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel_launcher.py', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-dc8af21c-af3f-488f-bfef-10c7b8e8f8ea.json']`

Here is another stackoverflow answer I tried to follow with no luck [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409167/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-magic-%C2%B4run%C2%B4-function-in-ipython)

## using %store

So trying this another route I decided to just store the variables / dataframes I wanted to pass in from notebook one to notebook 2. [Here is an example of that with an answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621414/share-data-between-ipython-notebooks), [And another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935670/share-variables-between-different-jupyter-notebooks). Yet, when I try to do it I have no luck. 
Code in Notebook 1:

```
%store df
```

output of that cell `Stored 'df' (DataFrame)`
And in another cell

```
var = 1
%store var
```

output of that cell `Stored 'var' (int)`

Now on to Notebook 2:

```
%store -r df
%store -r var
```

Error Message `TypeError: 'PickleShareDB' object is not subscriptable`

I am not sure what the issue is, here is my current jupyter notebook setup and versioning. I have tried to restart Kernels. I am also using the same Kernel. These notebooks are in the same directory.
Current Jupyter notebook versioning:
[image]

Comment: This was long ago covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37534440/8508004). There are some fresher takes, like [here](https://jupyter-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook/parameterise/index.html). But it does seem like the current state of the documentation is misleading, unless I'm missing something. Plus, for another modern take on this type of passing, there is [IPytohn DataVault detailed here in reply to another similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621414/share-data-between-ipython-notebooks#comment105590651_41981233) and that specifically supports dataframes.

Comment: <continued> Plus there is [How to pickle or store Jupyter (IPython) notebook session for later](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34342155/8508004).

Comment: You didn't bring it up but there's another approach where you can also use parameters in a URL to pass variables into a notebook, see [jupyter-notebookparams / Jupyter Notebook Params](https://github.com/manics/jupyter-notebookparams). Adding it because others ending up here might like to know that.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to, convert notebook2 to a Python file using Jupytext. Alternatively, read on for using `%run` a different way to accomplish much the same.

You can though use `%run` with notebooks to some extent. You've already seen that it doesn't pass args like you expect. Importantly for your plans, it turns out that by default it runs it in the same namespace as the source notebook, even without the `-i` flag.

### Using `%run`: Relying on the fact the second notebook is in the same namespace to share assigned variables

For `notebook1.ipynb`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
#import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np
import os
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import random
import warnings
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:95% !important; }</style>"))

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

a = 1
b = 2
%run "notebook2.ipynb"
```

For notebook 2:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
#import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import random
import warnings
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:95% !important; }</style>"))

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

print(sys.argv)

print(a)
print(b)
```

(I commented out the reference to a package my environment didn't have to make your toy code, more toy.)

#### Using %store

Dataframes can be pickled and so that should work. You can indeed use pickled dataframes to store and read separate from using `%store` and so it should work.  However, you provide no reproducible example or toy data and so I cannot illustrate perfectly based on what you were doing. I can guess what you meant though and try to show that...

Notebook 1:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
from random import choice, randint
cities = ['London', 'Delhi', 'Tokyo', 'Lagos', 'Warsaw', 'Chongqing']
df = DataFrame([
    {'salary': randint(0, 100), 'city': choice(cities)}
    for i in range(10000)
])
var = 1
%store var df
```

Notebook 2:

```py
%store -r var df 
print(var)
print(df)
```

Even trying other combinations more like your I couldn't get it to show what you report because this also works for Notebook 1:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
from random import choice, randint
cities = ['London', 'Delhi', 'Tokyo', 'Lagos', 'Warsaw', 'Chongqing']
df = DataFrame([
    {'salary': randint(0, 100), 'city': choice(cities)}
    for i in range(10000)
])
var = 1
%store df
%store var
```

And this also works for Notebook 2:

```py
%store -r var 
print(var)
%store -r df 
print(df)
```

So without more details about your example attempt, it is hard to say why yours didn't work.

Comment: For your %run example, this works for me to define the variables in notebook 1 and then print them in notebook 2. However the %store example still doesnt not work and I get the same error message. regardless if its a dataframe I am trying to retrieve or a basic atomic variable like var = 1.

Comment: Hmmm...For the %tore example, do you mean running the exact code I supply, it fails where you are using it?

Comment: yes exactly. It gives me that error message `TypeError: 'PickleShareDB' object is not subscriptable`. Regardless my work around is to just make a deep copy of the dataframe I declared in notebook 1 in notebook 2 as `df_notebook_2 = df_notebook_1.copy(deep=True)`

Comment: Glad you have a work around. My simple example should work well. I have seen in the past you can get pickle to be an issue when switching between versions of what seemed Python/pickle; however, here that shouldn't be the case. Since you have a work around, I wouldn't get to caught up on it now. I'll keep my eyes open for an actual issue but for now I'd write it off to some compatibility mistmatch probably in your environment somewhere that will hopefully not cause you too much hassle, and shouldn't occur when you go elsewhere.

Comment: agreed, thank you for the help and input!