# Is there a %store equivalent when running R in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I want to use an object (tibble) from one Jupyter notebook in another notebook, but I'm running R in both notebooks, and so the [%store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935670/share-variables-between-different-jupyter-notebooks) function does not work.

Is there an alternative when using R in Jupyter? Or is %store supposed to work here too? I could of course just download the tibble and re-upload it (as csv or whatever one wants to use) but I'm wondering if there is a %store alternative in this case.