# Jupyter Multiple Notebooks using Same Data

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have built out a Jupyter notebook for my previous analysis.
And I want to start a different branch of analysis, using the some of the same dataframes from previous analysis.

How do I use the previous dataframes without coping all my code to rebuild my previous analysis, in my new notebook?

Answer (score 4):

You can share [data across notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41981233/4531270) with [Jupyter magics](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#built-in-magic-commands).  For example:

**Given**

```
# Notebook 1
import pandas as pd


d = {"one" : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=list("abc"))}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Code**

```
%store df
```

Recall the DataFrame in a separate notebook:

```
# Notebook 2
%store -r df
df
```

Output

[image]

More on this in the [older IPython docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/storemagic.html). See also Jupyter's [`%bookmark` magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-bookmark) for sharing directories.

Answer (score 2):

You can pickle the dataframe then load the dataframe in your new notebook. This is fine for short term data reuse. For long term data storage, writing  then reading a text csv file may be more reliable.

pickle_save.py

```
import os
import pandas as pd

pickle_location = r'd:\temp\pickle_file'
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':1,'B':2}, index=[0])
df.to_pickle(pickle_location)
if os.path.exists(pickle_location):
    print('pickle created')
```

pickle_load.py

```
import os
import pandas as pd

pickle_location = r'd:\temp\pickle_file'
df_load = pd.read_pickle(pickle_location)
print(df_load)
```