# How to keep the same datatype after saving data to CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm saving data to CSV files using pandas. I have one important column with dtype: datetime64[ns].Somehow the datatype is changed to object when I read the data back from CSV file. How can I write, read while keeping the same datatype? Is this related to the encoding type?

```
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
df.to_csv(fileName)
df.TimeSeries
```

> Name: TimeSeries, Length: 10000, dtype: datetime64[ns]

```
DF = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep=',')
DF.TimeSeries
```

> Name: TimeSeries, Length: 10000, dtype: object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CSV files do not store data types. Data in CSV files is stored as text.

Your best options are:

1. Store in a serialized or other type-aware format (pickle, HDF5) if this is appropriate for your use case.
2. Use the `parse_dates` argument of `pd.read_csv`, e.g. `df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', parse_dates=['Date'])`. See `pd.read_csv` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for more details.

The second option is just a workaround. It will convert text back to `datetime` when you read the data into a dataframe.

Comment: I tried DataFrame.to_pickle and pandas.read_pickle. Works great. Thanks.

Comment: @Animate_Ant, great. Just be careful. Pickle is version-specific. It may not work across pandas versions. It also makes your solution Python-specific. But it's certainly efficient.

Comment: Actually, if you use a csv that quotes only nonnumeric types (Python `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` in `csv` library) then you can at least distinguish between numeric and string types.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, also I did not want to share the data temporarily. I wanted long-term storage which could **also handle data types**.

**Parquet** is what worked for me.

1. I read a CSV, **changed its dtypes**, and saved it as parquet

   `df.to_parquet("some-data.parquet", index=False)`
2. Read the parquet in pandas in other notebooks

   `pd.read_parquet("some-data.parquet")`

Note
You need to install a reader for pandas like fastparquet to do this in pandas

`pip install fastparquet`

Cheers.