# Importing a Dataframe from one Jupyter Notebook into another Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wrote a python script to get data from my Gmail account which I imported as a pandas dataframe into a Jupyter notebook. The notebook is called  "Automation via Gmail API" and the dataframe is simply called "df". Now I want to use this df to update a Google Sheet via the Google Sheets API. To this end I created another notebook - "Automation via Sheets API". But how can I access df in the "Automation via Sheets API" notebook? Apparently, [Jupyter provides some functionality to load a notebook into another notebook](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html#Notebook-Loader). I simply copy and pasted the code of the "Notebook Loader" into my Sheets-notebook and only changed "path" and "fullname", but it doesn't work and I don't have a clue why:

```
#Load df from the "Automation via Gmail API" notebook.

fullname = "Automation via Gmail API.ipynb"

class NotebookLoader(object):
    """Module Loader for Jupyter Notebooks"""
    def __init__(self, path="C:\\Users\\Moritz Wolff\\Desktop\\gmail automatisierung\\Gmail API"):
        self.shell = InteractiveShell.instance()
        self.path = path

    def load_module(self, fullname="Automation via Gmail API.ipynb"):
        """import a notebook as a module"""
        path = find_notebook(fullname, self.path)

[...]
```

There is no error-message. Is my strategy flawed from the start or do I simply miss a little detail? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You just have to click on "kernel" button, or anyway to choose the kernel, then select the notebook where there is the dataframe or any object you're interested in. To be the most clear possible, let's dfA is in notebookA and you want to use it in notebookB. So in notebookB you click on kernel and select notebookA instead of python 3.X that's by default. Then you access to all variables in notebookA if it's runned of course.

Comment: Can use parquet for long-term storage and preserving datatypes https://stackoverflow.com/a/73500091/5957834

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A direct option is to save the dataframe as a text table in the original notebook and read it into the other. Instead of plain text you can also save the dataframe itself as serialized Python for a little more efficiency/convenience.

Options from source notebook:

```py
df.to_csv('example.tsv', sep='\t') # add `, index = False` to leave off index
# -OR-
df.to_pickle("file_name.pkl")
```

Options in reading notebook:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.tsv', sep='\t')
#-OR-
df = pd.read_pickle("file_name.pkl")
```

I used tab delimited tabular text structure, but you are welcome to use comma-separated.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid loading your notebook from another notebook unless you are sure that is how you want to approach your problem.

You can always export your dataframe to a csv using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`
, then load it in your other notebook with `pandas.read_csv()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = ['test','data']
df.to_csv('data1.csv')
```

Then in your other notebook:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data1.csv', index_col = 0)
```

Alternatively you can try using the `%store` magic function:

```
df = ['test','data']

%store df
```

Then to recall it in another notebook to retrieve it:

```
%store -r df
```

One constraint about this method is that you have to `%store` your data each time the variable is updated.

Documentation: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html