# Trying to keep the same type after saving a dataframe in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

When I try to get my dataframe out of the csv file the type of the data changed. Is there a way I can avoid this?

[image: example]

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/73500091/5957834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv files does not have a datatype definition header or something similar.
So when your read a csv pandas tries to guess the types and this can change the datatypes.
You have two possibile solutions:

1. Provide the datatype list when you do read_csv with dtype and parse_dates keywords (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
2. Use a different file format that store data with a schema (ex parquet)

for example:

```
import pandas as pd
date = pd.to_datetime('01-01-2020')

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':['a','b','b','d'],'col3':[date,date,date,date]})

print('original \n',df.dtypes)

df.to_csv('testtype.csv',index=False)
df_csv = pd.read_csv('testtype.csv')
print('simple csv read \n',df_csv.dtypes)

df_csv = pd.read_csv('testtype.csv')
print('csv datatypes \n',df_csv.dtypes)

df_csv = pd.read_csv('testtype.csv',parse_dates=[2])
print('csv with parse dates \n',df_csv.dtypes)

df.to_parquet('testtype.pqt')
df_pqt=pd.read_parquet('testtype.pqt')

print('parquet  \n',df_pqt.dtypes)
```

that output:

```
original 
 col1             int64
col2            object
col3    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

simple csv read 
 col1     int64
col2    object
col3    object
dtype: object

csv datatypes 
 col1     int64
col2    object
col3    object
dtype: object

csv with parse dates 
 col1             int64
col2            object
col3    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

parquet  
 col1             int64
col2            object
col3    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is really helpful. I do get errors from parquet 'ArrowInvalid: ("Could not convert GPX', I don't know if this is compatible with gpx data? @riccardonizzolo

Comment: I don't know about GPX data, probably you should post another question on this topic. Please accept the answer if your initial question is solved

Answer (score 1):

CSVs are text files so don't inherently contain meta-data like datatypes.

When you're opening the CSV you've saved, Python/Pandas is interpreting what it thinks the datatypes are - presumably it's getting it slightly wrong compared to what you want (this is what's happening rather than your CSV being saved with the wrong datatypes).

Pandas 'read_csv' has a 'dtype' argument which will take a dictionary of column types. This should let you specify what data types you'd like. [I'd suggest reading through the function documentation here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .csv if you add record with false data in single row that acts as metadata if easily recognized as correct data type when interpreted upon loading. For example add generic string in field that needs to be object, but would otherwise load as integer or float.