# Setting CSV field type as string, but still numeric when opening CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, string, arcpy

I'm trying to use pandas to make sure that a CSV file is outputting certain fields (containing numbers) as strings, not numbers:

```
# lst of column names which needs to be string
lst_str_cols = ['FIPS_BLOCK', 'FIPS_BLKGR', 'FIPS_TRACT','FIPS_PLACE']
# use dictionary comprehension to make dict of dtypes
dict_dtypes = {x : 'str'  for x in lst_str_cols}
# use dict on dtypes
df = pd.read_csv(output_files_dir + "//" + output_shp_name + ".csv", dtype=dict_dtypes)
df.to_csv(output_files_dir + "//" + output_shp_name + ".csv")
```

While the code runs fine with no errors, the CSV still has `FIPS_BLOCK, FIPS_BLKGR, FIPS_TRACT, and FIPS_PLACE` as numeric - i.e., `5.50791E+14.` Is there anything I can do to ensure it outputs properly?

Comment: Can we see some sample data from the csv file as if you opened it up in a text editor?

Comment: you could probably try `df = df.apply(str)`

Comment: Please give us something we can use. Instead of reading a CSV, how about just initializing a dataframe with a couple of the columns and a couple of rows? or, post a small sample CSV and get rid of that `output_files_dir + "//" + output_shp_name + ".csv"` in favor of say, "test.csv".

Comment: The problem may be that you applied "str" to the columns in the first place. What are the native data types?

Comment: Why post a question and then go dark?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single row with an actual string for each column, ideally the first record, then all subsequent data will be interpreted as strings. However, this creates a record that needs to be considered for actual analysis, as the fields have irrelevant data. Having one string will force that interpretation. The problem is that the data type will not be defined in the CSV, when/wherever the file is read those fields will need to be interpreted. Pandas has done well for me for determining FIPS fields as objects(string), but the same CSV will load in excel or Arc software as integers without leading zeros. Each differs based on internal software interpretation of data. See also: [Trying to keep the same type after saving a dataframe in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62128730/trying-to-keep-the-same-type-after-saving-a-dataframe-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).