# Is it possible to move move a jupyter notebook and resume operations?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a `Jupyter` notebook where I have done an intensive operation. I would like to copy the Jupyter notebook to a different file, and resume operations from there. Unfortunately, `dill.dump_session` errors out with a fairly deep error on the zmq backend. Is there any way I can simply copy the notebook to a different name, and connect the current notebook's connection to the new name so that I can resume operations from that file?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: that is correct. it is not possible. the python kernel work cant be transferred at all to a new session.

Comment: have you thought about `threading`? that might help out with the intense operation.

Comment: Or share data between notebooks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621414/share-data-between-ipython-notebooks

Comment: @yascho %store magic requires me to list out the variables to share. I simply want to keep the current notebook running, just under a different name.

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I simply want to change the URL by which I access the notebook, but keep the analysis done so far available.

Comment: If it's not possible to duplicate notebooks, you can run notebooks in a virtual machine and then start duplicated versions of that VM.