# How to access variables defined in one ipynb file into another in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to access variables defined in one ipynb file into another in jupyter notebook.
My code:

```
mymodel.ipynb
```

```
import import_ipynb
import utils

N = 12
```

```
utils.ipynb
```

```
x, sr = librosa.load(path)
S = librosa.stft(x, N)
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'N' is not defined
```

I have also tried

```
from utils import *
```

Comment: Have you tried `from ipynbfile import some_variable`? It works for .py files, but I don't know the situation for `.ipynb`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share data between IPython Notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621414/share-data-between-ipython-notebooks)

Comment: @emremrah I have tried from filename import *

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%store` command.

more information can be found [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/config/extensions/storemagic.html) and [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/)

In source notebook

```
data = 'data to read'
%store data
```

In destination notebook

```
%store -r data
#now u can access data from source notebook
```

Comment: I need to refer various variables in various ipynb files, Are you proposing I should apply the same solution for all?

Comment: once you use `%store` command in source ipynb then that data can be accesed in any ipynb files so yes you can use same solution for all

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the following way,

In source jupyter notebook file, define the variables with value
e.g:

```
userName = 'PriyabrataSamantaray'
```

In the other destination ***Jupyter*** notebook, call the file as below

```
%run /Users/priyabrata.samantaray/ConnString
```

Here the *connString* is the name of my source jupyter notebook

```
getusername = userName
print(getusername)
```

The output in the destination Jupyter notebook  will be *PriyabrataSamantaray*
This code can be used in Databricks jupyter notebook